# A good database modeling tool for PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, data-modeling

PostgreSQL comes with the excellent pgAdmin-tool for managing the database but lacks GUI data-modeling utility?

I found this list: http://www.databaseanswers.org/modelling_tools.htm
but don't have time to evaluate them.

Which one do YOU recommend?

Comment: Dbeaver provides diagrams, but not reverse engineering from models - https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/ER-Diagrams

Comment: See [Moon Modeler](https://www.datensen.com) - data design tool that offers data modeling, reverse engineering and forward engineering features. Free version is  available.

Answer (score 14):

pgModeler looks promising: http://pgmodeler.com.br

Comment: I really like the interface/functionality but unfortunately it's still extremely buggy.  I wouldn't do any work with it that you wouldn't mind completely losing (I learned this the hard way).

Comment: pgModeler is quite stable now, I'm using v0.9.3 with no problems. To compile it you can follow this guide I wrote https://medium.com/@mglaving/how-to-compile-pgmodeler-0-9-3-on-ubuntu-20-04-19f045ec5b1d

Answer (score 7):

You might also want to have a look at Power*Architect.

http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect

Answer (score 6):

**[WWW SQL Designer](http://code.google.com/p/wwwsqldesigner/)** is a great lightweight modeling tool, and it supports PostgreSQL.

**[SQuirreL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/)** also seems nice, I haven't tried it though.

Comment: This is the online version of WWW SQL Designer:
http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/

Answer (score 3):

The MySQL workbench is a fine modeling tool that's free, but you'll have to modify the SQL it generates for PostgreSQL.

If you have to pay, ERWin is a standard.

Comment: ERWin doesn't support PostgreSQL. FYI.

Comment: but generated mysql code can be converted into postgresql

Answer (score 3):

Commercial tools:

[dbwrench](http://www.dbwrench.com/)

[Embarcadero ER Studio](http://www.embarcadero.com/products)

Answer (score 3):

I've been satisfied for years with [PostgreSQL Maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com). It's a mature solution and easy to use, but comprehensive.