# How to start pgAdmin Database Designer?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Is there a tool equivalent to "phpMyAdmin's designer view", so I can create my database graphically. And vice versa, create a graphical view from an existent database?

**Note**:
This is not a duplicate of 
[How to access the pgadmin database designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101818/how-to-access-the-pgadmin-database-designer), because the asker wanted a "Graphical Query builder".

Comment: You are looking for a "ER Modeler". pgAdmin does not have one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2927895/330315

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the reply, lacking for such a tool for PostgreSQL is a bad thing  :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [DbVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/download/), to generate a graphical view of my database. I strongly recommend to use this easy to use tool. It comes with many database drivers, among them the driver of PostgreSQL. I consider this as an answer because it responds to my needs, I hope this will help someone one day.

Answer (score 1):

Update 2021: The brand new PGAdmin4 has an integrated ER modeler now: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pxVCzRFGeg

[image: Here's an example]